# Table display issues ; awkward rows display

Tags: php, html, css

I didnt had this problem with my previous scripts but for this case the result was this :

[image]
Notice the awkward gap for each table rows ? I tried maximising the width of table to standardise but couldnt improve much with `<width:500px>`

My source code for the 2 tables are :

```
//check whether period falls under new projects
$sql2a= "SELECT projectname, from_unixtime(startdate + (15*3600), '%y %m %d') AS StartDate, projectvalue, from_unixtime(enddate + (15*3600), '%y %m %d') AS EndDate, from_unixtime(projectedenddate + (15*3600), '%y %m %d')AS ProjectedEndDate, from_unixtime(completiondate + (15*3600), '%y %m %d') AS CompletionDate, from_unixtime(closeddate + (15*3600), '%y %m %d') AS ClosedDate, from_unixtime(createddate + (15*3600), '%y %m %d') AS CreatedDate, id FROM projects WHERE startdate BETWEEN '{$startdate}' and '{$enddate}'";
$sql2a = mysql_query($sql2a);
echo "<header><font size'3' color='Green'> New Projects </font></header>";
while($sqlrow = mysql_fetch_array($sql2a))
{
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Project Name</th>
<th>Start Date</th>
<th>Project Value</th>
<th>End Date</th>
<th>Projected End Date</th>
<th>Completion Date</th>
<th>Closed Date</th>
<th>Project ID</th>
<th>ID</th>
</tr>";

 echo    "<tr>".
         "<td>".$sqlrow[0]           . "</td>".
         "<td>".$sqlrow[1]           . "</td>".
         "<td>".$sqlrow[2]           . "</td>".
         "<td>".$sqlrow[3]           . "</td>".      
         "<td>".$sqlrow[4]           . "</td>".
         "<td>".$sqlrow[5]           . "</td>".
         "<td>".$sqlrow[6]           . "</td>".
         "<td>".$sqlrow[7]           . "</td>".
         "<td> <form action='ListProjectDetails.php' method='post'> ".
         "     <INPUT type='submit' value='{$sqlrow[8]}' name='submitid'> </form> </td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "<br></br>";
//check whether period falls under completed projects
echo "<header><font size'3' color='Blue'> Completed Projects </font></header>";
$sql2b = "SELECT projectname, from_unixtime(startdate + (15*3600), '%y %m %d') AS StartDate, projectvalue, from_unixtime(enddate + (15*3600), '%y %m %d') AS EndDate, from_unixtime(projectedenddate + (15*3600), '%y %m %d')AS ProjectedEndDate, from_unixtime(completiondate + (15*3600), '%y %m %d') AS CompletionDate, from_unixtime(closeddate + (15*3600), '%y %m %d') AS ClosedDate, from_unixtime(createddate + (15*3600), '%y %m %d') AS CreatedDate, id FROM projects WHERE closeddate BETWEEN '{$startdate}' and '{$enddate}'";
$sql2b = mysql_query($sql2b);
while($sqlrow2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2b))
{
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Project Name</th>
<th>Start Date</th>
<th>Project Value</th>
<th>End Date</th>
<th>Projected End Date</th>
<th>Completion Date</th>
<th>Closed Date</th>
<th>Created Date</th>
<th>Project ID</th>
</tr>";

 echo    "<tr>".
         "<td>".$sqlrow2[0]           . "</td>".
         "<td>".$sqlrow2[1]           . "</td>".
         "<td>".$sqlrow2[2]           . "</td>".
         "<td>".$sqlrow2[3]           . "</td>".         
         "<td>".$sqlrow2[4]           . "</td>".
         "<td>".$sqlrow2[5]           . "</td>".
         "<td>".$sqlrow2[6]           . "</td>".
         "<td>".$sqlrow2[7]           . "</td>".
         "<td> <form action='ListProjectDetails.php' method='post'> ".
         "     <INPUT type='submit' value='{$sqlrow2['8']}' name='submitid'> </form> </td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: you should to close table </table> and follow table structure correctly - between/after/before <tr> only <tr> allowed, inside <tr> only  <td> inside <td> everything valid html

Comment: You are generating different tables, so column size differs. You can use one table. See my answer for detail.

Answer (score 2):

You are generating different tables, so it is normal to differ column size. I am giving example for the first one only, you can apply it to second one also. You can use following;

```
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Project Name</th>
<th>Start Date</th>
<th>Project Value</th>
<th>End Date</th>
<th>Projected End Date</th>
<th>Completion Date</th>
<th>Closed Date</th>
<th>Project ID</th>
<th>ID</th>
</tr>";

while($sqlrow = mysql_fetch_array($sql2a)) {

 echo    "<tr>".
         "<td>".$sqlrow[0]           . "</td>".
         "<td>".$sqlrow[1]           . "</td>".
         "<td>".$sqlrow[2]           . "</td>".
         "<td>".$sqlrow[3]           . "</td>".      
         "<td>".$sqlrow[4]           . "</td>".
         "<td>".$sqlrow[5]           . "</td>".
         "<td>".$sqlrow[6]           . "</td>".
         "<td>".$sqlrow[7]           . "</td>".
         "<td> <form action='ListProjectDetails.php' method='post'> ".
         "     <INPUT type='submit' value='{$sqlrow[8]}' name='submitid'> </form> </td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: May I see your website? Is it accessible? Have you applied it to all tables?

Comment: yes i did. its in UAT so cant show on the web. Anyway I have to seperate them because I need to label each of them as an individual table entity. Do u have any other alternatives ?

Comment: You have applied `<width:500px>` also remove them. You dont need to separate in to tables.

Comment: yep i removed but it still persists. Like i say i cant include all in one table due to the need of labelling each group of information seperately.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we should add the closing table:

```
echo "</tr></table>";
```

Comment: doesnt work. tried for all 3 tables. Perhaps you could elaborate more ?

Answer (score 0):

Set the table width to 100% then set the width on each td.